# How to migrate from SQL Server 2016 on premise to Azure SQL Hyperscale

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am planning to migrate SQL Server 2016 on premise database of around 6tb (2 database) to Azure SQL hyperscale. I want to know what kind of challenges i can face during migration.

I have already run DMA (Database migration Assistant), it has thrown issues related to cross database reference. Are there any other tools i can use to find out migration blockers. What are the features of SQL Server 2016 on prem that are not supported on Hyperscale?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for raising the question and contributing to Stack Overflow.

- Yes, you can migrate SQL Server 2016 On Prem to Azure SQL Hyperscale.
- You can use all existing migration technologies to migrate to Hyperscale, including transactional replication, and any other data movement technologies (Bulk Copy, Azure Data Factory, Azure Databricks, SSIS). See also the [Azure Database Migration Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/dms-overview), which supports many migration scenarios.
- Go through these docs for more reference :

[Hyperscale Service Tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale#what-are-the-hyperscale-capabilities)

[Data Migration Questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale-faq#data-migration-questions)

[List of Tools for Migration Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/dms-tools-matrix)

I hope this information helps.